# Multiple Live Search Laravel using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Can someone help me to find out what's wrong with my code?

I'm trying to search in 2 forms using AJAX

here is my code

Blade

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(orderno = '', jobno= '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
   method:'GET',
   data:{orderno:orderno,jobno:jobno},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
   }
  })
 }

 $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var orderno = $(this).val();
  var jobno = $(this).val();
  load_data(orderno,jobno);
 });


 $(document).on('keyup', '#searchkanban', function(){
  var orderno = $(this).val();
  var jobno = $(this).val();
  load_data(orderno,jobno);
 });



});
</script>
```

and this is my Controller

```
    {
      if($request->ajax())
      {
          $output = '';
          $query = $request->get('orderno');
          $query2 = $request->get('jobno');


          if($query != '' && $query2 == '')
          {
            $data = DB::table('scankanban')
              ->where('sk_orderNo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')

              ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
              ->get();

          }

          else if($query != '' && $query2 != '')
          {
            $data = DB::table('scankanban')
              ->where('sk_orderNo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
              ->Where('sk_jobNo', 'like', '%'.$query2.'%')

              ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
              ->get();

          } 
          else // get all if not found
          {
            $data = DB::table('scankanban')
              ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
              ->get();
          }

          $total_row = $data->count();

          if($total_row > 0)
          {
              foreach($data as $row)
              {
                $output .= '
                <tr>
                <td>'.$row->sk_orderNo.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->sk_jobNo.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->sk_orderKanban.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->sk_scanID.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->sk_status.'</td>
                </tr>
                ';
              }
          }
          else
          {
              $output = '
              <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
              </tr>
              ';
          }
          $data = array(
              'table_data'  => $output,
              'total_data'  => $total_row
          );

          echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

1. I can get all data it means the `else` code is working
2. When I type in form #search, I can get query search.
3. When I typed in form #search and form #searchkanban, the result was empty table like not found. Sometimes get data but wrong data. I updated this code from https://www.webslesson.info/2018/04/live-search-in-laravel-using-ajax.html. Before only use 1  search form, now I want to use 2 search forms.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both `orderno` and `jobno` are got from `$(this).val()`. I think you made a mistake here.

Comment: oh my god, thanks you saved me @bravemaster. I change `$(this).val()` with #formname.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code. Thank you to @bravemaster. My mistake is only in #formname

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
 var orderno = $("#search").val();
 var jobno = $("#searchkanban").val();
 load_data(orderno,jobno);
 });


 $(document).on('keyup', '#searchkanban', function(){
 var orderno = $("#search").val();
 var jobno = $("#searchkanban").val();
 load_data(orderno,jobno);
 });
```